# Django when is order_by applied in the view?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I am using Django ModelViewSet. If I pass `?ordering=some-field` in the url, when is it applied on my queryset at the django level? I would need to catch some specific behavior there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `filter_queryset` method, each filter backend in the list of `filter_backends` is called and the queryset is passed to it. I assume you're using the DRF `OrderingFilter` which is a filter backend. So that is where it is called and the queryset is ordered.

You can check the `OrderingFilter` class to see how you can modify/override the behaviour